# Selecting dataframe rows by condition on column

Tags: python, dataframe, select

I have a dataframe with 6 column the first one of which represents a Date.

I want to select only the rows with a specific date represented in the first column, how should I do  ?

The dataframe is loaded via read_csv and contains 6 columns , as strings , the first one represents a Date and the remaining ones are representing integers

I was using :

df['Data' == '....'] which I found somewhere around the net

Initially the first column , 'Data', was included in the index_col=[] list in the read_csv : I kept getting error on that same column, so figuring it could be caused by the index_col list, I completely eliminated it, to  no avail.
After that I tried thousands of other methods , none of them worked .

Is there a way to do it or should i simply give up the idea ?

This is the code :

```
l = [{'Data' : '2023-07-11','Val1':'2','Val2' :'23', 'Val3':'2','P':'0','Totals':'12'},
     {'Data' : '2023-08-01','Val1':'3','Val2' :'0', 'Val3':'21','P':'0','Totals':'2'},
     {'Data' : '2023-01-09','Val1':'4','Val2' :'41', 'Val3':'51','P':'1','Totals':''},
     {'Data' : '2023-04-12','Val1':'5','Val2' :'210', 'Val3':'30','P':'0','Totals':'1'},
     ]

orig_df_stats = pd.DataFrame(l)


print (orig_df_stats)

print (orig_df_stats['Data' == '2023-07-11'])
```

Comment: dput () doesn't seem to be  a legal call in Python....

Comment: Please [edit] your post with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1422451). Better to show than tell us your sample data and code block in the body of your post.

Comment: Oops sorry I  overlooked the part where it said python  try df.to_dict() instead

Comment: You mean using df.to_dict() to visualize the dataframe ? or to implement the select operation that I don't seem to be able to ?

Comment: so you can add reproducible data to your question

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is this:

```
orig_df_stats[orig_df_stats['Data'] == '2023-07-11']
```

Comment: why doesn't the same call work when the dataframe is loaded from a .csv file ?

Comment: uhh include the csv file data? @BoojiBoy

Comment: Here are a couple of rows from the file  :                                                                                  Data                                         Val1 Val2 Val3  P      Totals                                                                      
2023-07-15 00:00:00.000 3 45 0 300 300
2023-07-15 00:00:00.000 30 36 0 300 300
the file seems to be correctly formatted as I am able to load it as a dataframe and visualize it with a print() statement